# A long-running operation is being executed on the main thread.

Tags: ios, multithreading

I am performing a segue from one storyboard to another (from one view controller to a TabBarController in another storyboard). I am getting this warning:

```
 Warning: A long-running operation is being executed on the main thread.
 Break on warnBlockingOperationOnMainThread() to debug.
```

I know all UI updates are done on the main thread. Here is my code:

```
 DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeTabViewController") as! HomeTabViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
```

To my knowledge DispathQueue.main.async{} is the way to get the main thread and perform UI stuff in iOS, yet I still get this warning, and (more importantly), the app pauses probably a 0.5 to 1 full second between when the segue button is pressed and when the segue is actually ran, whereas it should be instantaneous.

Any ideas to fix it?

Comment: check your destination ViewController viewDidLoad, or ViewDidAppear or ViewWillAppear, there must be your issue

Comment: I commented out all code in viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear, still getting the issue